# Presto implementation of @CombineFunction for Aggregation that requires ordered input values

Tags: java, sql, partitioning, presto, trino

Imagine I want to develop a Presto `AggregationFunction` that requires an ordered input to work correctly. It will be invoked as follow:

```
WITH my_table AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES
            ('a', 1),   -- worker 1
            ('a', 2),   -- worker 2
            ('a', 3),   -- worker 2
            ('a', 4),   -- worker 3
            ('a', 5),   -- worker 3
            ('a', 6),   -- worker 3            
    ) AS t (key, val)
)
SELECT key, MY_AGG_FUNC(val ORDER BY val)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY key
```

Will the data processing be split among workers behind the scenes? If so, are there any guarantees that the splits will be merged back "in order" as well? e.g

- OK: (workerState1 + workerState2) + workerState3
- OK: workerState1 + (workerState2 + workerState3)
- NOT OK: workerState2 + (workerState1 + workerState3)

In other words... Do I have to implement the following:

```
@CombineFunction
public static void combine(@AggregationState MyState mySate, @AggregationState MyState myOtherState);
```

and can I assume that `myState` and `myOtherState` are **contiguous** and **in order**?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of speculation because Presto does not seem to have very good documentation on the subject.  I don't even see anything that suggests that `ORDER BY` is supported in UDFs (although it is supported in some built-in functions)

> Will the data processing be split among workers behind the scenes?

The data processing should be.  But this split should be at the `key` level.  All values with a given key should be sent to the same node.

> If so, are there any guarantees that the splits will be merged back "in order" as well?

It is hard for me to imagine an implementation where the rows are not ordered *before* the aggregators are called -- if the syntax supports `ORDER BY`.

Unfortunately, I consider "guarantee" to be "documented behavior", and Presto is pretty short on that front.